# How to split __DATE__ and __TIME__ macros into individual components for variable declarations?

Tags: c++, c, date, macros, c-preprocessor

I have the following structure (on an embedded system):

```
struct Calib_Time_struct
{
    uint16_t    year;
    uint16_t    month;
    uint16_t    day;
    uint16_t    hour;
    uint16_t    minute;
    uint16_t    seconds;
};
```

I have a "default" values array, in which I need to insert time values:

```
struct Calib_Table_struct
{
    unsigned int                    table_id;           //!< Table identifier.
    char                            group_name[CAL_TBL_MAX_GROUP_NAME_LENGTH];
    unsigned int                    channel_number;     //!< Channel number within the group.
    float                           floor_value;        //!< Minimum value for a channel.
    unsigned int                    size;               //!< Number of elements in the table.
    struct Calib_Time_struct    modification_date;  //!< Date of modification.
};
static const struct Calib_Time_struct default_values[] =
{
    // Table 0
    {
        .table_id = 0U,
        .group_name = "ADC",
        .channel_number = 0U,
        .floor_value = 0.0f,
        .size = 1,
        .modification_date =
        {
            .year       = /* extract from __DATE__ macro */;
        },
    },
    //...
};
```

I would like to fill in the year, month, and day of the "modification_date" member from the `__DATE__` macro.

Is there a method to do this?
(Any hacks?)

Can a similar method or hack be applied to the `__TIME__` macro?

The motivation is to allow the compiler (on a build server) to plug in the values automatically, rather than having a developer do this.  We have many developer's on the team, and use the build server to make "official" builds that are delivered to people outside our team.

The data will be attached to the executable and stored in Flash, downloaded by a bootloader into memory.

There are a lot (over 80) tables in the default array.

My tools:
IAR Systems IDE & Compiler: 7.4
Embedded Systems platform using ARM Cortex-A8.

Languages:  primarily in C, but may be useful for C++ language folks.

Comment: `default_values` is not a constant expression, so you could just fill it dynamically at the start of you program, no? (not perfect perf wise, ik)

Comment: `default_values` is a constant expression, and to keep things simple to update, this structure is not modified before or in `main()`.

Comment: No it is not. It’s just a const object, the compilation doesn’t depend on its value being available. You can simply initialize it with a function call which parses the `__DATE__` string using C or C++ instead of PP. I don’t know what you mean by »simple to update«, you can certainly have compile time as your requirement, but currently that’s not stated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C spec guarantees that `__DATE__` will be a string literal of the form

```
MMM DD YYYY
```

with the first digit of the date being whitespace if the date is a single character long. This means you could do Cruel and Unusual Things like this, which technically speaking isn't portable (the preprocessor doesn't have to use the same character encoding system as the target), but should probably work:

```
#define YEAR_CHAR 7
#define YEAR  (\
                ((__DATE__)[YEAR_CHAR + 0] - '0') * 1000 + \
                ((__DATE__)[YEAR_CHAR + 1] - '0') * 100  + \
                ((__DATE__)[YEAR_CHAR + 2] - '0') * 10   + \
                ((__DATE__)[YEAR_CHAR + 3] - '0') * 1      \
              )
```

The `__TIME__` macro is guaranteed to have the form

```
hh:mm:ss
```

and so you could similarly do something horrible like this:

```
#define HOUR_CHAR 0
#define HOUR (\
                ((__TIME__)[HOUR_CHAR + 0] - '0') * 10 + \
                ((__TIME__)[HOUR_CHAR + 1] - '0') * 1    \
             )
```

to get the hour, or the minute, or the second.

If you have a C++14-compliant compiler, you could use `constexpr` functions to compute this less horribly:

```
constexpr int compilationYear() {
    const int kYearChar = 7;
    const int kNumYearChars = 4;

    int result = 0;
    for (int i = yearChar + kNumYearChars - 1, multiplier = 1;
         i >= kYearChar;
         i--, multiplier *= 10) {
        result += (__DATE__[i] - '0') * multiplier;
    }

    return result;
}
```

You could then assign something the value of `compilationYear()` and will evaluate that function at compile-time.

Comment: @zneak You know, I didn't check. I assumed this was one of those things that got incorporated from the C spec, but I haven't confirmed this.

Comment: It may well be. I don’t know either.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply initialize it using a runtime call to a parsing function for the `__DATE__` macro (»Mmm dd yyyy«, which means the chars for the year are at known positions):

```
int extractYearFromDateMacro() {
    return 1000 * (__DATE__[7] - '0') + 100 * (__DATE__[8] - '0') + 10 * (__DATE__[9] - '0') + (__DATE__[10] - '0');
}
```

---

```
    .modification_date =
    {
        .year       = extractYearFromDateMacro()
    },
```

From C++11 you can add `constexpr` in front and have the compiler evaluate it. (also for use in constant expressions)

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d01b1eff4b84023c)

The same method can be applied to the `__TIME__` macro ("hh:mm:ss") as well.

Using the preprocessor won’t even guarantee you compile time evaluation if you only concatenate expressions. These may still be evaluated at runtime.

`extractYearFromDateMacro` above will probably be constant folded the same way the result of PP expansion would.

In contrast using the `constexpr` approach will guarantee compile time evaluation.

Comment: __ DATE __ produces "Jul  9 2019", arduino ide 1.8.9

Comment: @Codebeat according to the other answer the format is guaranteed, so your compiler is non-conforming and it would be nice of you to file a bug report. For practical purposes, i’m sure you can adjust the given function accordingly. Since in your case it seems to be variable length, i would save it into an `std::string` and index from the end with the help of its `size()`.